# Stored procedure with global table

Tags: sql

Is there any difference between stored procedure which uses global temporary  table and one which does not in MS SQL database?

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Global temporary table's scope is not limited to stored procedure, it can conflict with other procedures using same global temporary table(`##TableName`)

You can create Global temporary table in procedure, insert data and then see your data after store procedure execution.